# Combined system() and popen()?

Tags: c, system

Edit2: Thinking it over, here might be a better question:

If I use popen to write to a sysfs file, it blocks until the write is completed, but doesn't wait for the sysfs file to finish handling it. How can I wait for that sysfs file to do whatever it is doing?

I want to run a command within a program, wait for it to finish (which will take a few seconds) and return the terminal output to me, without printing it to the console.

From reading other questions, I have seen that the `system()` or `exec()` calls can be used to run a command. However, these do not give you the output of the terminal, so you need to do something clunky like write to a file and then open and read that file and then delete it.

The other option I have seen is `popen()`, which gives a file descriptor you can use to get the terminal output. However, this does not seem to wait for the command to finish, which resulted in my program screwing up a bit.

So how can I get the functionality of popen while forcing it to wait for the child process to finish before doing anything else?

Edit: Here is what I am currently doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    char terminal[512];

    sprintf(terminal,"/bin/cat /home/Config/BASE_SETTINGS.bin > /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\:device3/profile_config");
    if(!(file=popen(terminal,"r"))){return -1;}
    while(fgets(terminal,sizeof(terminal),file)!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n", terminal);
    }
    pclose(file);
}
```

This is part of the program, I do the same thing several times, just changing the command in "sprintf" each time. From what I've been told pclose should block. However, when I run the command from a terminal, it takes several seconds after writing to the sysfs file before it finishes configuring. However, when I do this via program, the program runs in less than a second.

Because the later commands  in my program rely on the sysfs driver being configured, and it appears to be going to later commands before the sysfs process is done, the later commands fail, as they end up being run before the configuration is complete.

Comment: popen() does wait.  See also pclose()

Comment: Please show your code. `popen` does not wait but `pclose` does. But your question may suffer from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem). Please provide details of "which resulted in my program screwing up" bit so that we can more readily point out what the right approach is to solving that which is your actual problem (it may or may not involve `popen`).

Comment: Just a detail: `popen()` gives you a file stream (`FILE *`), not a file descriptor (`int`).

Comment: If you loop reading the output from the command run via `popen()`, the reading code should hang until there's more data or the command terminates (more precisely, closes its standard output which is being read by your process).  At that point, you will get back read errors indicating EOF.  Without your code, it is hard to know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @kaylum I added a snippet of code I'm using

Answer (score 0):

pclose() and _pclose() (on windows) will block until execution of the subprocess has completed. To get the output, just open them up with a FILE pointer and read from them with fgets. See the below example (for both win32 and unix systems):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
    #include <Windows.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif

#ifndef PATH_MAX
    #define PATH_MAX 255 //Usually defined in <Windows.h>
#endif

FILE *popenHandler(const char *args, const char *method)
{
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        return _popen(args, method);
    #else
        return popen(args, method);
    #endif
}

int pcloseHandler(FILE *fp)
{
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        return _pclose(fp);
    #else
        return pclose(fp);
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp; //file pointer to point to command
    char path[PATH_MAX]; //char buffer to store output

#if defined(_WIN32)
    char command[PATH_MAX] = "dir"; //command to execute
#else
    char command[PATH_MAX] = "ls -l"; //command to execute
#endif

    //If you want to include stderr in the results, uncomment the below string
    //strncpy(command, " 2>&1", PATH_MAX); //Merges stderror with stdout

    fp = popenHandler(command, "r"); //function to work on win32 or unix
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Failed to execute command %s\n", command);
        return -1;
    }
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("Line #%i of output from command: %s\n", lineNumber++, path);
    }
    int returnValue = pcloseHandler(fp); //Make sure to close!
    printf("The sub-process returned %i\n", returnValue);
}
```

Comment: What I am seeing doesn't seem to follow this. I am writing to a sysfs file to load some configurations. When I do this from a command prompt, it takes several seconds for the sysfs to do whatever it does. But when. I do this in a program, the program finishes immediately. This makes it seem to me like the program is moving on before the configurations are loaded properly.